# LibreOffice Base: Query Token error

Tags: sql, libreoffice, radix

I have a question about use a multiple functions in **LibreOffice Base**. I cant use the `IF()` inside de `SUM()` Here is the statement:

```
SELECT Item.idArticleType, 
SUM( IF(Item.isNew = false, Item.stock , 0)) as 'oldStock',
SUM( IF(Item.isNew = true , Item.stock , 0)) as 'newStock'
FROM 'Item'
GROUP BY 'Item.idArticleType'
```

This statement works on MySQL, but in **LibreOffice Base** gives me a Message:

> Unexpected token: IF in a statement

Any help?

Comment: I assume in my answer that LO Base is using this same MySQL database as the engine.  If it is using something else instead, such as embedded HSQLDB, then please mention that.

Comment: After trying it using HSQLDB, it looks like that produces the error.  Did you intend to use the HSQLDB engine?  If so, then the syntax will be different.  Otherwise, fix the LO Base file so that it uses MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if quotes are removed, whether entered at a MySQL prompt or from the Queries area in Base.

```
SELECT Item.idArticleType,
SUM( IF(Item.isNew = false, Item.stock , 0)) as oldStock,
SUM( IF(Item.isNew = true , Item.stock , 0)) as newStock
FROM Item
GROUP BY Item.idArticleType
```

The result:

[image: query in LO Base]